# how to find a control's location based on the control's name

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I want to basically find a control's location based on name. This is what I have so far:

```
private Point FindControlLocation(string ControlName, Control ParentControl)
{
    //Code...
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the parent control, just use the Form and the recursive option from `Controls.Find()`:

```
private Point FindControlLocation(string ControlName)
{
    Control ctl = this.Controls.Find(ControlName, true).FirstOrDefault() as Control;
    return (ctl != null) ? ctl.Location : new Point();
}
```